# Question about diagonal of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

1. Does a diagonal of a parallelogram always separate the parallelogram into two congruent triangles?
2. If a diagonal of a quadrilateral separates the quadrilateral into two congruent triangles, is it necessarily a parallelogram?

Comment: Start with the definition of a parallelogram (see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parallelogram.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes the diagonals of parallelogram separate parallelogram in to two congruent triangles.
2. No, this is not necessarily true, for example in the case of kite or in the case of concave quadrilateral with two pairs of equal length adjacent sides, each of them have diagonals which separate quadrilateral in to two congruent triangles, but these are not parallelograms.